# Can't mirror Ubuntu 16.04 to Crestron AirMedia

Tags: airplay

I succeeded in mirroring Ubuntu onto AirPlay (only after I configured a password to AirPlay) via the command **java -jar airplay.jar -h hostname[:port] [-a password] -d** on port 7000. But no success with AirMedia, I tried all the possible ports but it gave me an error massage: **java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)**

Comment: Why don't you just use over http//IP ?

Comment: How? what do you mean by over http//IP? I need to transmit it, if I surf to the air media IP's it says it have a client for Mac or Windows only.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck getting this to work? with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS